# How to use Scrapy with Spyder or VScode

Tags: beautifulsoup, scrapy

I hope you all are fine and doing well.
I want to use Scrapy with Spyder instead of Using it through terminal/shell. I'm a windows user, Scrapy version 1.8.0 , pyhton 3.7.3, I'm facing issues with BeautifulSoup.
For example I'm trying to fetch price of a product from a website, the issue is it does not always get the data but Scrapy working perfectly here by using CSS Selector.
so i want to use Scrapy with Spyder or Vscode because i also have other code that will be dependent on Scrapy's Output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually you would need a sort of editor in other to program your spider to crawl and scrape of the web, the shell is more like a testing environment before you get to the good stuff og actually programming your spider. So from the terminal

```
$workon my_virtual
```

To work on a partcular virtual environment. cd into the appropriate directory

```
$pip install scrapy
```

To install scrapy in your virtual environmnet

```
$scrapy startproject myspider
```

This gets everything you need up and running in the directory you are in.

```
$scrapy genspider <spidername> <base_url>
```

this will generate a spider for you automatically. For more details on how, you might want to refer to the [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) documentation.

You can execute python scripts with another python program using the subprocess module.

```
def otherfunc(crawler_output):
    #do something with the gotten out put  

def myfunction():
    os.chdir('scrapy directory')

    subprocess.Popen(['scrapy', crawl], shell=True) 

    output, err = Popen.communicate()
    os.chdir('initail working directory')
    otherfunction(output)
```

This method directly get output from the scrapy crawler which is on the shell and feeds it to your code. Another method which is more secure with similar principles would be

```
def otherfunc(crawler_output):
    #locate the file within your directories
    #do something with the gotten out put  

def myfunction():
    os.chdir('scrapy directory')

    subprocess.Popen(['scrapy', crawl, name, -o, file.csv], shell=True) 


    otherfunction(file.csv)
```

This way you will be dealing with a file, but the contents of the file would have been the results gotten from scrapy

Comment: This is again same, I want it to work with my other code, For example I have code of Scrapy and also want it to work with my Other code in same File.

Comment: Great effort, But
I'm making a bot on cloud, the main code will fetch links from database, then main code will call all bots that will fetch data according to my need and will return that all back to main code other code working fine with BeautifulSoup but for this one i have to use Scrapy, I will not able to run any script or making any environment for scrapy, Is there any method ? that i will only have to create object of that class and call fetch method so all done automatically ? Scrapy code must also work with my other code that is dependent on it's output.

Comment: Then have the results of the result of the crawl stored on a database instead of a file file format, and pull from that database. Scrapy makes saving scraped results to a database easy